# Try except with If statements in Python

Tags: python

If I'm trying to prompt a user for their street name and they enter a # symbol i want to return an error and loop back to the top until they have entered a valid name.

Code:

```
def streetname():
    while True:
        try:
            nameinput = str(input("Please enter a street name: "))
        except Exception: # want to print error == if nameinput.find('#') > -1:
           print("Error: name contains #, please try again")
           continue 
        break
    return nameinput
```

Goal of code: I want to prompt user for street name until they enter a valid name. If it contains '#', print error and try again. if it's valid, return nameinput.

I'm not quite sure how to use try and except with if statements

Comment: Why use `try` at all here? Entering a "#" doesn't make `input` crash, so there's nothing to catch. Why not just do `if "#" in nameinput:`?

Comment: You don't need to cast `input(...)` to `str`; it is already a string.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't use `try...except` for such a simple input check, that can easily done with if alone.

```
def streetname():
    while True:
        nameinput = input("Please enter a street name: ")

        if "#" in nameinput:
            print("Error: name contains #, please try again")
            continue

        return nameinput
```

If you find a '#' in the string simply restart the loop, otherwise just return the name out of the function.

Also `input` already returns a `str` in Python 3, so there's no need to convert it. In Python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead which will also return a `str`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're using a python's general Exception class.  A string with a pound sign in it wouldn't trigger any of python's native exceptions, you have to write your own exception class and then call it.. or you can do something like this

```
if '#' in nameinput: #pound sign was found in the string
  #either raise an Exception
  raise('Can not use pound sign') # though this will probably break the while loop
  # or
  print 'can not use pound sign'
  continue # to go back to the top of the while loop and prompt the user again
```

Comment: Thanks for updating!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters no problem. Happy for the discussion. Gets thoughts flowing.